# Installing Drivers on a Virtual Machine?

Tags: drivers, usb, virtualbox

I'm on a Ubuntu PC and running VirutalBox with a Windows 8.1. 
I want to Use my AverMedia LGP Lite USB Capture Card, but I cannot find any drivers for Linux, so I was wondering if I could use it with a VM. 
I got so far that the Guest detects my USB device but when I try to install the driver it says

> Can't update Drivers for PlugAndPlay devices

I did some googling and from what I understand the VM has no connection to any hardware. VirtualBox virtualizes every hardware, I guess using the driver installed on the host system?

So does that mean, if there is no driver on the host system it cannot work in the guest system?

There isn't any way to use or install drivers onto the guest os?

So maybe the only way is to use dual boot with windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use passthrough functionality to redirect your hardware directly to your Guest.

In the past I've used hardware not supported by host, but supported by guest OS. It was an old scanner which had not been working with Windows 7 because of lack of Windows 7 drivers. But it worked in Windows XP guest. So the answer to your question:

> So does that mean, if there is no driver on the host system it cannot work in the guest system?

No. It could work in the guest system if it supports it.

Here's general [instructions](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=82639#p390401):

> A USB filter is a series of "AND" conditional statements. So when
>   you're filling in the filter values, you're telling the filter:
>
> > Capture a device with this VendorID, AND that ProductID, AND ...
>
> A blank filter (not recommended!) will match anything, which is good
>   if the device appears as a composite, i.e. presents as a number of
>   different devices all connected at once. However the danger of a blank
>   filter is the potential to grab the wrong device, e.g. you do not want
>   to grab the host's USB keyboard and assign it to the guest! If you
>   have a problem with the wrong device being grabbed then you'll need to
>   add just enough information to the filter so that it matches your
>   device only. But don't define the filter too narrowly, as that can
>   lead to problems too. That's why your safest bet for a basic filter is
>   to fill in the VendorID and ProductID only. The proper checklist for
>   capturing a USB device with a filter is:
>
> 1. Make sure that the Extension Pack (ExtPack) is installed on the host. The ExtPack must be the same version as the main VirtualBox
>      program. The ExtPack is not the same as the Guest Additions! The
>      ExtPack is installed on the host and adds support for a virtual USB2
>      host controller. VirtualBox 5.x.x added USB3 (xHCI) support as well.
> 2. Make sure that at least USB2 (EHCI) is enabled in your VM settings. If your guest supports USB3 (xHCI), use that. See "Guest support"
>      below. It is important to note that if your guest supports USB3, you
>      should definitely enable that, even if your host does NOT support USB3
>      at the hardware or software level, mainly because the USB3 stack is
>      much better designed compared to USB1 and USB2.
> 3. Under **VM Settings » Port » USB**, create a USB filter in your guest settings while the device is plugged in the host. Delete all
>      values except **Name, VendorID and ProductID**. The Name is nothing
>      more than a label and is not actively participating in the filtering
>      process. You can change it at will. I usually use "Stick: XYZ" or
>      "Joystick: ABC" or "Other: IJK".
> 4. Unplug the device.
> 5. Start your guest (the one that you applied the filter to). Let it start completely. Log in if you have to, reach the desktop, and wait
>      until any disk activity has stopped.
> 6. Plug your device. The filter should capture it and pass control to your guest.

Troubleshooting info you could find on referenced page. If general info did not help, read the full article and apply recommendations.

Comment: You are my hero man thank you! Works great now!

Comment: You're welcome) Glad it helped.